# Javascript, extending class with Array with iterator support

Tags: javascript

I found a very weird behavior, I'm using Firefox 93.0 64 bits, lets pick the next example:

```
class SubArray extends Array{
 constructor(...i){
  super(...i)
 }
}
```

The intuitive behavior, is that this new class should do the same as a normal array, with all their properties, but does not do that, we get the next in the console.

```
a=new SubArray([1, 2, 3])
a[0]
Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

We are not getting the first element....

How can we extends a class to array, and appropriately inherit properties? (all of them, set elements, get elements, etc, etc)

Thx,

Comment: You're getting the same thing you would get if you did `a = new Array([1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: If you want an array with 3 elements, it should be `new SubArray(1, 2, 3)`. Don't put `[]` around the arguments.

Comment: I see, this is a little confusing, because of how we declarray in first place, (we don't need   new), yeah, that fix it.

Answer (score 0):

as @Barmar says.

This will works if we do `new SubArray(1, 2, 3, 4)`, this is because there is a difference betwen the builtin classes and the user classes, in the builtin classes we use `[1, 2, 3]`, we are not using the normal user constructor, so the equivalence would be `new Array(1, 2, 3)`.

Just to keep in mind, if we are using builtin classes from JS, we need to check how JS translate the usual form like `[]` to the usual constructor, other example would be, how `{1: 'hi'}` is translated to the Object constructor?, just keep in mind this question.